# Exception Unhandled: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Tags: python

I'm receiving the error 'Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement' when I run the following code:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
from pw import * # Imports password from another file
from datetime import datetime


db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="zac",
    passwd= pww,
    database="testdatabase"
    )

mycursor = db.cursor()


namee = input("What is your name? ")
brandd = input("What laptop brand do you own? ")


# mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE Laptop (brand varchar(50) NOT NULL, created datetime NOT NULL, id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name varchar(50) NOT NULL)")

mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO Laptop (brand, name) VALUES (%s,%s)", (brandd, datetime.now(), namee))
db.commit()
```

My aim is to get the users input saved in the server. I'm not sure what the error is as I'm pretty sure I've covered every parameter.

Comment: You have only 2 `%s` but 3 parameters `(brandd, datetime.now(), namee)`. -> Couldn't use all parameters.

Comment: @Karthick_Raju and @h4z3 If I put 3 `%s` I get the following error: "1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Comment: It's not simply about adding additional `%s` as you just told the insert that you will provide two values `(brand, name)` - you have to add the info that you want to add the third one as well, like TOTO said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO Laptop (brand, created,name) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)", (brandd, datetime.now(), namee))
```

You should have the same number of params—i.e., `%s`—as the column name you put in the parentheses before the `VALUE`.